# About a theorem involving the radical of an ideal

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, math-history

It's a well-know theorem in (commutative) ring theory that if $I$ is an ideal of a commutative ring $R$, then its radical $\sqrt{I}$ is equal to the intersection of all the prime ideals of $R$ containing $I$. I've been searching for different proofs about this result and every proof that I've found uses Zorn's lemma, so my questions are: is there a proof of the result above without using Zorn's lemma? is this result equivalent to Zorn's lemma?

Finally, an historical question: who proved this theorem first?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement that $\sqrt{I}$ is an intersection of primes implies the existence of prime ideals in nonzero commutative unital rings.  In fact, they are equivalent: First, replace $R$ with $R/I$.  If $f$ is not nilpotent, then pulling back a prime of $R_f$ gives a prime of $R$ not containing $f$.

What is the relationship between the existence of prime ideals and the axiom of choice?  There is a lot of discussion of this in the mathoverflow thread [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98549/existence-of-prime-ideals-and-axiom-of-choice).

In short, the axiom of choice is equivalent to the existence of maximal ideals, but the existence of prime ideals is weaker, and equivalent to the [Boolean prime ideal theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_prime_ideal_theorem), which is a widely-used weakening of the axiom of choice.